# Loop for minimum spanning tree does not work

Tags: r, for-loop, conflict, minimum-spanning-tree

we as 3 friends try to solve minimum spanning tree with coflicts problem using r. In solving this question, we read files in .txt format that contain for ex.
"1 2 5
2 4 6" etc. which indicates from node 1 to 2, there exists an edge with weight 5 and
"1 2 2 4" etc. which indicates there's a conflict relationship between the edges 1-2 and 2-4. To continue, we have to form an nxn conflict matrix in which we will store 0's if there exist no conflict relation between the edges or 1 if there exist a conflict relation. For this purpose, we developed a 3-for loop for(i in 1:dim(edges_read)[1]){

```
for(i in 1:dim(edges_read)[1]){
  for(k in 1:dim(edges_read)[1]){
    for(t in 1:dim(conflicts)[1]){
      if(all(conflicts[t,] == c(edges_read[i,1], edges_read[i,2],
                                  edges_read[k,1], edges_read[k,2]) )){
        conflictmatrix[i,k] <- 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, R cannot get us a solution and this for loops take very long times. How can we solve this situation? Thanks for further assistance

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide some sample data? Also, it seems that the first `for` statement was dropped.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, `for()` loops are not fast in R. There are faster approaches, but it's hard to provide examples without data. Please use something like `dput(edges_read)` and `dput(conflicts)` to provide a small example of the data.

As one example, you could implement the for loops in the Rcpp package for speed improvement. Based on the code in your question, you could re-implement the 3-loop code sort of like this:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector MSTC_nxn_Cpp(NumericMatrix edges_read, NumericMatrix conflicts){
int n = edges_read.nrow(); //output matrix size (adjust to what you need)
int m = conflicts.nrow();  //output matrix size (adjust to what you need)
NumericMatrix conflictmatrix( n , m ); //the output matrix 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ //your i loop
  for(int k=0;k<n;k++){ // your k loop
  double te = edges_read( i, 0 ); //same as edges_read[i,1]
  double tf = edges_read( i, 1 ); //same as edges_read[i,2]
  double tg = edges_read( k, 0 ); //same as edges_read[k,1]
  double th = edges_read( k, 1 ); //same as edges_read[k,2]
  NumericVector w =  NumericVector::create(te,tf,tg,th); //this could probably be more simple
    for(int t=0;t<m;t++){   //your t loop
        NumericVector v = conflicts( t , _ ); // same as conflicts[t,]
        LogicalVector r;   //vector for checking if conflicts and edges are the same
        for(int p=0; p<4; p++){  //loop to check logic 
          r[p]=v[p]==w[p];  //True / False stored
        };
        int q = r.size();
  for (int ii = 0; ii < q; ++ii) {  //similar to all() This code could be simplified!
    if (!r[ii]) {false;}
  else{conflictmatrix[i,k] = 1;}}
  }}}
  return conflictmatrix;  //your output
}')

#Then run the function
MSTC_nxn_Cpp(edges_read, conflicts )
```